# Sent MNT in Mantle blockchain using ASTR destination, how to recover?

Tags: astar

I made a stupid mistake: I wanted to move some ASTR from EVM address managed by Metamask, to native address managed by polkadot.js. But I initiated transaction in Metamask while being on Mantle blockchain. I pasted my native polkadot.js-format Astar address into Astar portal, but transaction was sent on Mantle blockchain. Some amount of Mantle coin went to ECDSA 0x... address, for which I think I have private key, but how do I get it? Is it the same private key as in my Polkadot.JS account? I'm software engineer working with crypto, so I will be able to write some code to get what I need, please just point me in right direction.